# Difference between AC3 and EC3?

Tags: audio, surround-sound, dolby, atmos

Hi I was studying the concepts of the structure of AC3, it is described as an object-oriented audio codec, is it right to define it as such and why?
What is the difference in wave compression compared to EC3 for being an object-oriented audio codec?

Comment: Ricardo - just be clear exactly what it is you are looking for here. Atmos itself is just raw audio streams with metadata. There are different ways of delivering them depending on the display format - DCP/Cinema or Consumer. In the latter case Dolby Digital Plus (EC-3) is used (as opposed to AC-3 for Dolby Digital (5.1ch). Are you looking for info relating to the differences between AC3 and EC3 ?

Comment: @Mark yes that's right, I'm also trying to understand the relationship between the two and their differences

Comment: ok, understood. I think it would be a good idea to re-write the question and description so that this is clarified.

Comment: In the meantime, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Digital_Plus has a lot of good information the EC3 compression methodology.